# Does LaTeX3 address the subject of scope (i.e. grouping)?

Tags: latex3, grouping

TeX scope is an overwhelmingly convoluted and opaque subject. It is impossible to tell by sight when a scope starts and ends, and what exactly is being affected by it. Since scope is one of the fundamental building blocks of every programming language, this is one aspect of TeX that, in my opinion, desperately needs an overhaul from the ground up. Does LaTeX3 address this subject?

---

I was asked:

> What do you mean by ”impossible to tell by sight“?

I'm not even talking about pathological examples like

```
\def\mymac{a}%
\input enigma %redefines \begingroup and \endgroup as \relax
\begingroup%
    \def\mymac{b}%
\endgroup%
\mymac%
\bye%
```

which typesets

```
b
```

(Could you tell it by sight?)

I'm talking about normal examples, like the fact that the `{...}` in `\def<control sequence>{...}` do not imply a grouping, but the `{...}` in `\output{...}` do imply a grouping, yet the `{...}` in `\mymacro{...}` don't imply grouping, whereas the `{...}` in `\loop{...}\repeat` do imply grouping.

I'm talking about the fact that `\setbox<number> = ...` is local, but `\ht<number> = ...` is global (could you tell it by sight?), and when you create a plain TeX box, the current font will be captured in the box, but the current color won't.

And this is just to give you a taste.

Comment: To be honest, your questions are very weird.  For example this very question.  LaTeX3 is implemented in TeX (what else?) and therefore shares the same grouping concept as the underlying engine.  So no, LaTeX does not change the scoping rules.

Comment: Note that the team explored and rejected local register assignments precisely because they don't make life easier (they suggest a functional-like approach to scope which doesn't exist in TeX).

Comment: Actually the grouping of TeX is really great thing.  The C preprocessor, as another example for a macro language, does not have a concept of grouping which makes all definitions global and errors really hard to track.  BTW, I voted to close as unclear.

Comment: a LaTeX document is build with environments, and an environment is also local scope delimiting. So "impossible to tell by sight" is a bit strange here. Of course there are subtleties like automatically global assignments or the way dimensions of boxes are handled.

Comment: Of course, devious programmers may hide grouping in macros without documenting it. Other than that, grouping is usually well understandable from the typescript. What do you mean by ”impossible to tell by sight“?

Comment: The size of a box _isn't_ global:`\setbox0=\hbox{A}
\begingroup
\setbox0=\hbox{g}
\showthe\dp0
\dp0=2pt
\endgroup
\showthe\dp0` (it's set _at the group level of the setting of the box_).

Comment: Most of your examples are very low-level: I don't really see the link to `expl3`/LaTeX3 (where the entire point is to provide a higher-level set of interfaces). One can't avoid the fact that the argument to macros, _etc._ is a _balanced text_ which can also be used for grouping, though in LaTeX3 code we've gone for `\group_begin:`/`\group_end:` exclusively for the latter.

Comment: @JosephWright: I guess it just goes to show that McDougal wasn't a *true* [Scotsman](http://www.iep.utm.edu/fallacy/#NoTrueScotsman).

Comment: The colour example is really nothing to do with grouping: colour isn't 'native' to TeX so has to be added as a `\special`, and there are issues with building that in to _all_ boxes at a code level. (If one goes LuaTeX-only it can be done without issue, but that's using an entirely different approach to colour from that we use in other engines.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

LaTeX3 (and in particular `expl3`, the programming layer) is written in TeX so ultimately cannot change the way TeX works. However, it can provide documented interfaces which detail how particular concepts are to be used.

For grouping, `expl3` thus has to work with the various constructs TeX uses. The major ones are `{`/`}` (catcode 1/2 pair group) and `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` (semi-simple group): the latter in `expl3` are renamed as `\group_begin:`/`\group_end:`. The way that these work is simple: they create a group in which local assignments will be 'trapped'. Reflecting this, `expl3` provides a range of `\<thing>_set:Nn` and `\<thing>_gset:Nn` (or similar) macros which either locally or globally set the `<thing>`. The latter will usually be a variable such as `\l_tmpa_tl` (a token list to be set locally), `\g_tmpb_clist` (a comma list to be set globally), *etc.*

There are some TeX constructs which can only be set globally. However, these are largely low-level and are not generally exposed by `expl3`. Where they are, the documentation is clear that they must be handled using global interfaces: they will be given `\g_...` names. (For example, `\prevgraf` is *not* exposed by `l3galley` but there is a `\g_galley_previous_par_lines_int` variable which covers the same concept.)

As LaTeX3/`expl3` is still in development, there are places where TeX primitives are not yet covered or where some changes may still be needed (box dimensions may well fall into the latter). However, the general approach is clear: document the scope, name appropriately and provide higher-level interfaces for a range of low-level concepts.

---

One of the examples in the question is that `{` ... `}` may be used for (at least) two reasons:

- To create a *balanced text* argument
- For grouping

The two are linked as TeX determines something is a *balanced text* as it is enclosed as a group using begin-group and end-group tokens. However, for `expl3` code we have favoured (as a convention) using `\group_begin:`/`\group_end:` only for grouping: any `{` ... `}`  pairs appearing in code are therefore arguments.

---

On the example of setting box height/depth/width, this is an area in `expl3` which may still need attention. One may imagine dealing with the slightly odd behaviour by using appropriate wrappers to allow setting the box 'correctly'. That is not (yet) done, and has performance implications. On the other hand, the box code is relatively lightly reviewed at present: this may change. (I've raised with the team: I have a plan of sorts.)

Comment: "name appropriately" - ouch. IMO `\prevdepth` is an appropriate name - it clearly suggests it's the depth of a box used previously, which is correct. On the other hand `\g_galley_previous_par_lines_int` is longer to type, doesn't talk about boxes at all, and it's not clear (to me) whether its referring to "the total number of lines in the previous paragraph" or "the number of lines processed previously in the current paragraph". I'll pass over the question of exactly what a "line" is means here - and how could the value *not* be an integer, unless you have some concept like "half a line!" ...

Comment: ... reminds me of the Devil's Dictionary definition of Structured Programming: "A simple way to increase the length of a computer program, without significantly improving its performance" ;)

Comment: @alephzero An answer about `expl3` is never going to please people who dislike the entire approach :)

Comment: @alephzero I've corrected which primitive I meant: `\prevgraf` not `\prevdepth` (and yes, the integer business is an open issue: `l3galley` is certainly not finished and the entire business of lines _versus_ space, for example for paragraph shape, is tricky).

Comment: So let me understand. `expl3` renames all of TeX's primitives, and those primitives that are not susceptible to grouping, like `\fontdimen`, have names starting with `g_`, while all the others, like `\def` or registers, have names starting with `l_`?

Comment: @EvanAad No, we rename all the primitives as `\tex_<name>:D` then build up a language based on those (which are 'Do Not Use': other interfaces are provided where needed). At present, things like `\fontdimen` don't have a documented `expl3` interface _a all_: I suspect we'll never directly expose such things.

Comment: @EvanAad Please see `texdoc expl3` (for an overview)/`texdoc interface3` (code-level interfaces in `expl3` 'core').

Comment: The `g_`/`l_` naming approach sounds to me like a reasonably good way to tackle the issue, as long as it is consistently and thoroughly applied throughout LaTeX3.

Comment: @EvanAad Please see our docs: we are _very_ clear about naming approaches